# Installing pip in different versions of python

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, python-2.5

I have multiple versions of Python installed(2.5,2.7). I am using Ubuntu. Python2.7 is my default Python interpreter. So all packages like PIL is installed in python2.7. Now i want to install some packages in Python 2.5 version.
I need to install Pip so that i could install the packages. Now i do understand some would give the advice of virtualenv. I tried that too.
But installing Pil through that too doesn't show the packages in the python2.5 version. It installs it in python2.7 version. So i need to do something so that when pip installs the package it installs it in Python2.5 version. Any suggestions?

I also tried this:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.5 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.5
```

but it says no module named pip

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer: [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

You have to try like this if pip >= 1.5:

```
$ pip2.5 install SomePackage 
$ pip2.7 install SomePackage
```

Else:

```
$ pip-2.5 install SomePackage  
$ pip-2.7 install SomePackage
```

Comment: I tried that. It worked but i wasn't able to get the package to properly work. I wanted to install PIL or Pillow.

Comment: The _imagingft C module is not installed. I was able to find the unofficial libraries for windows and it contained the right package but for ubunutu, there aren't any.

Comment: did you install `apt-get install libjpeg-dev` 
`apt-get install libfreetype6-dev`
`apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
`apt-get install libpng12-dev` ???

Comment: I did, but they are installed for the default python version only i guess. I need it working for 2.5. All of the above packages are installed.

Comment: As I checked, Pillow < 2.0.0 is supported in Python2.5, so can you try: `pip-2.5 install Pillow==1.7.8` ?

Comment: I tried that too, installing Pillow gives other error like missing freetype/fterrors.h

Comment: I am not sure about this suggestion, if you are open for testing, I will suggest you something I am not sure will work or not. download pillow for python(64/32 bit doesn't matter) 2.5 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil, extract exe, from PURELIB folder of that extracted file, copy and paste `PIL, pillow-egginfo folder` to your python25/.../sitepackages folder. check what happens.(I know its windows distribution, but those are compiled files)

Comment: That is a clever advice but the .egg file will be containing windows somewhere in it which can cause an error. Though i will surely give it a try. Thank you for your patience, time and help.